# Magento 2 install setup - blank page

Tags: php, magento, server, magento2

It's my first time with Magento shop. I try to install it on my web server (shared hosting) and got blank page with little grey stripe on the top.

My steps:

1. Download ZIP file with Magento
2. upload package on my web serwer via FTP
3. open URL with magento setup
4. Got blank page (screen below)

I was trying magento 2.3 with PHP 7.2 or Magento 2.2 with PHP 7.1 and also few other configurations. Always the same problem: blank page with grey tripe on the top. Where can be problem? Hosting provider told me that there is no errors, but maybe Magento need something more. Someone told me that Magento need at least 512MB of memory, so I made changes in php.ini file even to 756 and nothing...

No PHP errors. In /var/log/debug.log I have this mesages:

```
[2019-01-28 23:14:15] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
```

[image: blank page MAGENTO setup]

Comment: It can be a file permission issue otherwise it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Magento either by CLI or webinterface.

follow these official instructions

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install-roadmap_part1.html

Comment: Hmmm that is really strange... Today I opened URL setup page, and... Install wizard has started! Blank page is gone. I also made few other sub-domains to test it few times. I downloaded Magento 2.2 and 2.3 and everytime all is fine, and setuup wizard starting. I thing that hosting provider changes something but they will not tell me that. Maybe there was something missing...?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the websetup to be honest. setup:install is always my way to go

Comment: Hmm, even if you installed it the way you mentioned above, did you run a composer install after the files were copied over?

Comment: please read the full documentation on how to install Magento2